# If I make changes to bdc, will the changes propagate to pdc?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I have 2 bdc and of course a pdc. If some of our admins have been making changes to the bdc, will they propagate up to the pdc? If not, will these settings be overwritten?

How does that work?

Comment: why the heck am I getting down voted?!?! This site never ceases to amazing me in the amount of downvotes it hands out.

Comment: Lack of research effort.. http://i.imgur.com/gEmn3z8.png

Comment: By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions can attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or missing details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no PDC or BDC after Windows NT4 . Every DC can make changes in AD data. Latest change wins. So, yes, you can make the update on any DC and it will be replicated to all of them in the same domain.

If you change the same attribute on 2 different DCs at the same time, latest change will overwrite.